# Why is "Windows Update Cleanup" missing from my Disk Cleanup?

Tags: windows-7, disk-cleanup, hotfix

I'm trying to get rid of the excessive files inside the `winsxs` folder. However, there is no "Windows Update Cleanup" option in my Disk Cleanup dialog. I am told that installing this [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2852386) enables the option.

After installing the hotfix, there is still no option for "Windows Update Cleanup".

Comment: The reason is simply this: "Windows will only give the option to clean up Windows Updates if it can find any that have been superseded or are no longer needed for any reason." Check out here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a3d0e5b-5009-4cb7-bac5-ab38ac5e9584/windows-update-cleanup-option-is-missing-when-running-disk-cleanup?forum=winservergen

Answer (score 7):

Run disk cleanup [as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) to get the option shown. When you run it as normal user it only shows data for your local account but no system settings.

Comment: Still no "Windows Update Cleanup" with this, Windows 10

Comment: @sdbbs which windows version? from time to time Windows does this on its own during normal install you see a message calling "cleanup".

Answer (score 6):

For some reasons I wasn't able to see "Windows Update Cleanup" either with a Local Admin and Domain Admin.

I ended up loading DiskCleanup with this preset:

> %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c Cleanmgr /sageset:65535 & Cleanmgr
>   /sagerun:65535

Comment: That didn't do it for me either. It opened an empty cleanup dialog quickly, but when I clicked OK it just started scanning again and ended with the regular one without that option.

Comment: For me too, neither Local nor Domain Admin worked. When opened with given preset, it gave me the option for Windows Update Cleanup. On clicking OK, it started scanning and disappeared (auto closed) after scanning. Not sure how many different behaviours one operating system can have... Any advices to get around?

Comment: Running this command in Administrator Command Prompt does show a "Windows Update Cleanup" entry, though it says "deletes or compresses", and "you might need to restart your computer"

Answer (score 6):

As neither of the proposed answers worked for me directly, I put here the steps I have to do in order to get "Windows update cleanup" option:

1) Make sure that `KB2852386` is installed. You can check in `Programs and features` -> `Installed updates`. If it is missing, you can install `x64` version from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40359). It requires a restart and some patience before it is fully configured (at startup).

2) You can either run `Disk Cleanup` as `Administrator` OR run it normally + press `Clean up system files` and the option will show.

Answer (score 3):

There is another workaround

From an elevated command prompt, type the following:

```
Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
```

Then

```
Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase
```

A full explanation can be found at
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder